# wp7: highlight selected image within a listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, selecteditem

I have a list box where I'm displaying a list of icons.  I want to highlight the selected item by changing the icon color from 'white' to 'blue'.  This sounds simple to me, but it seems to be very difficult.

Does anyone have suggestions on the best approach to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to change the actual color of the icon or highlight the selected item in the `ListBox`? If it is the latter, then add a `SelectionChanged` event handler. Within this handler do the following:

```
var lb = sender as ListBox;
var lbi = lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lb.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;

lbi.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Blue );
// or
lbi.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Blue );
```

If you wish to reset the `BorderBrush` for the previously selected item, take a look at the [`SelectionChangedEventArgs.RemovedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property. You can use code similar to what I've posted to reset the color.

Comment: i would prefer to change the color of the icon.  i am currently highlighting the selection by changing opacity but that is a second choice.

Answer (score 1):

For first case you need to create two icon images one for selected and another of normal view.
you can change image in list box on selection change event as bellow

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string imgUri = "selectedImageName.png";

        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.UriSource = new Uri(imgUri, UriKind.Relative);

        (listBox1.SelectedItem as Image).Source = bmp;

       // for resetting unselected items  
       BitmapImage bmp1 = new BitmapImage();
        foreach (var v in e.RemovedItems)
        {
            imgUri = "imageNameForNormalView.png";

            bmp1.UriSource = new Uri(imgUri, UriKind.Relative);
            (v as Image).Source = bmp1;
        }

    }
```